# How to remove a Linux Distro from mulit-boot

Tags: partition, multiboot

I have on my PC isntalled Windows 10, Ubuntu, Linux Mint, Fedora, Zorin OS and Elementary OS. I want to delete a few of them. Is it as simple as deleting the partitions? The only problem is that I cant backup my Drive because it's 1TB. Also, if I delete the first (default) OS, will this affect the other distros? Thanks in advance!

Edit: The distros I want to delete are Ubuntu, Fedora and Zorin OS

The output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`

```
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xa8ade033
```

but it also says

```
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

Comment: It depends, from which OS have you installed Grub?

Comment: @ShahFahad Ehm, hard to say, I have the Fedora Bootloader, on top of Zorin Bootloader, on top of the Usual Grub. (I currently use the bootloader from fedora, since its the last installed distro)

Comment: Don't Fedora and Zoring use grub bootloader. I think what you meant to say is Fedora's Grub bootloader and Zorin's grub bootloader. What is a usual grub?

Comment: @ShahFahad probably that, I am a bit confused with how bootloaders work

Comment: I suggest you to have a basic idea of the bootloader before attempting to use the process specified in answer because if some unexpected things occur it can make your pc unbootable. Also keep a live usb of any `os` handy, just in case.

Comment: @ShahFahad I do know the basic stuff about how they work but not anything too complicated. Also I dont format the USB after installing distros.

Comment: The entry `Disklable type` specifies that you have `dos` partition table (not `gpt`) which is also called `MBR`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified that you have `BIOS firmware` and `dos` partition table. For this setup, you can remove `os's` by removing the partitions containing the `os's`. Just boot into an `os` which you want to keep. Remove the partitions containing `os's` you want to remove (do not poweroff/reboot at this point).
Now make sure that you have `os-prober` installed so that remaining `os's` can be automatically detected while installing grub, then install `grub` from currently booted `os` using `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`, that's it. You can now reboot.

Comment: can I use```os-prober``` to find out wich partitions are wich? Also the command doesnt show 2 distros, ```Fedora``` and ```elementary os``` (which I am currently using)

Comment: `os-prober` will not list the `os` from which you have booted. Say for eg you booted into `fedora` and then you ran `sudo os-prober`, then it will not list `fedora`, because it is obvious. Also `os-prober` specifies the partition on which the `os` is present. For eg it may show an output like: `/dev/sda2:Ubuntu ...`, this means `Ubuntu's` `root` partiton is present on `sda2` partiton of disk `sda`

Comment: I actually meant that I booted on ```elementary os``` and I couldnt see ```fedora```.

Comment: @Games08 can you see `elementary-os` from `fedora`? There can be some issue, you will have to do some research and find the cause.

Comment: Yes I can see elementary os from fedora. I will try some things I have in mind and I will let you know if they worked.

Comment: So I tried ```sudo grub-install``` but I got this error ```Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: error: install device isn't specified.
```

Comment: @Games08 Edited by answer to specify that. Basically you will have to specify a storage device on which you want to install grub, in your case it would be /dev/sda. Run the command `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`. Read this, it will take you step by step on how to install grub. https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Installing-GRUB-using-grub_002dinstall.html

Comment: After many tries I could not fix my problem, but I was wondering, what if I delete a distro (not the default) using GParted?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply remove the partitions of the `os` you want to remove provided you don't mess up the bootloader you use for booting. I am assuming you have `UEFI` firmware and you want to keep one of your linux distro. Boot into the distro which you want to keep, then when you are deleting a partition, be extremely careful that `EFI system partition` is unmounted (Generally `EFI system partition` is mounted on `/boot/efi/` on linux), this is the partition where all the bootloaders are stored. You can use the `lsblk` command to see which disk partition is mounted where. Make sure `os-prober` is installed on your `os` so that other `os's` can be detected while updating the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. After removing the partition run the `update-grub` command. If `update-grub` command is not present on you distro, use `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` (backup this file before running any of these command). Finally reboot you machine and go to the `UEFI boot manager` by hitting `F12` or whatever and select the bootloader of the distro which is still present and boot from that bootloader. Keep in mind that the bootloder of other distros whose partition you deleted will also be present in the `UEFI boot manager` because the bootloader is still present in the `EFI system partition` but you will not be able to boot from them because the file which they source at the boot time i.e `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` has been deleted. To remove the bootloader entry of deleted distro's bootloaders from the `UEFI boot manager`, you can use the command `efibootmgr`.

Comment: Actually I use BIOS and I want to delete only some of the distros.

Comment: You must specify which `os` you want to keep. Be more specific

Comment: I edited my question above :)

Comment: @Games08 what partition table are you using i.e MBR or GPT? Also can you post the output of `sudo fdisk -l` and specify which `os` is on which partition.

Comment: Because I am not sure, I  think I use GPT because of [this](https://www.explorelinux.com/check-if-a-disk-uses-gpt-or-mbr-in-linux/#:~:text=sudo%20gdisk%20/dev/sda1), it outputed the same errors, but for the 
 next one, it says ```Partition Table: loop```. Do I have to check every partition or is it the same for the whole disk? Btw sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Partiton table is defined for entire disk and not for a single partiton. You edit this post and add the output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`, assuming your disk is `sda`. There is an entry `Disklabel type` in the output of `fdisk` command which specifies which partition table is present on disk.